# Why html2pdf generator is leaving gap and generating 1 extra page upon print

Tags: vue.js, html2pdf

Hi i'm using `html2pdf`  plugin.

**1st problem** is it is leaving gap and not occupying whole `A4` size paper as shown in below image

[image]

**2nd problem** it is adding 1 more extra page upon print

Please click on **Generate Pdf** button to see the pdf

here is what i have tried:

https://codesandbox.io/s/interesting-shamir-8bdo2x?file=/src/components/A4.vue

Answer (score 1):

For the first problem, you don't need to add CSS class for `A4.vue`. Rather then, you can add this CSS for A4 page :

```css
@page {
  size: A4 portrait;
  margin: 16mm;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 10pt;
}
@page landscape {
  size: A4 landscape;
}

@page portrait {
  size: A4 portrait;
}
```

For the 2nd problem, I don't get your question properly. I think you might not include the full `A4_no2.vue`

See the [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/xenodochial-ptolemy-y2vetx?file=/src/components/A4.vue). It may help you.

Comment: great !! but i wanted to know how many pages are there in ui and print should be exactly as shown in the ui  so i used `A4` class. can't we  add that back to know how many pages are there in my ui

Comment: hi @EaBengaluru you can get the page number using this `totalPages` section described here https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-html2pdf#sample-use-case-of-beforedownload. But you might not able to render the css  properly. https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-html2pdf#known-issues  see point -2.

But there is a hack for that , you can use inline css to make it effective

Comment: please check this very challenging question of mine and help me  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71736366/how-to-scroll-while-selecting-items-with-mouse-in-vue